# Auto-generated class members?

Tags: c++, class, auto

When creating a class, I know of 3 Constructors/Destructors which are auto-generated if you don't specify them. The `operator=` is also auto-created.

Is the `operator==` or any other comparison operator auto-generated? Are there any other members or member functions which are created? What about the `this` pointer?

Comment: There's also the copy-constructor, move-constructor, move-assignment operator that's auto-generated as well. Same conditions apply however.

Comment: The Big Three (C++03)/The Big Five (C++11) + default constructor.

Comment: What are the big 3/big 5. I assume the default constructor is the constructor, the copy constructor and the destructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [latest spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) I could find, section 12.1 states:

> 12 Special member functions [special]
>   1 The default constructor (12.1), copy constructor and copy assignment operator (12.8), move constructor
>   and move assignment operator (12.8), and destructor (12.4) are special member functions. [ Note: The
>   implementation will implicitly declare these member functions for some class types when the program does
>   not explicitly declare them. The implementation will implicitly deﬁne them if they are odr-used (3.2). ... ]